# In which case would you say Boreh Nefashot after Hamotzi?

Tags: halacha, hamotzi-beracha

My grandfather came across this packaging for bread which says on the bottom right to make Hamotzi on it and after say Boreh Nefashot. How could this be?[image]

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.208.9?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the ingredients, it seems that it is primarily made out of non wheat flour (nuts and seeds) but it does contain wheat flour. When determining the bracha rishona, the rule is that any wheat (if it is for flavor) is enough to establish the bracha as hamotzi (assuming it is not considered פת הבא בכסנין). But to say birkas hamazon, one would need to eat a kezayis of wheat within the shiur of kdei achilas pras. For this bread it seems that would be impossible and therefore the bracha acharona is borei nefashos.

Comment: "impossible" Surely Kobayashi could eat the whole loaf in under a minute